# If $A_{mn}$ is increasing for each index m,n, can we change the order of limit

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A_{mn}$ is a real for each index $m,n$. And for each fixed $m$, $A_{mn}$ is increasing, i.e., $A_{m(n+1)}\ge A_{mn}$, and for each fixed $n$, $A_{mn}\le A_{(m+1)n}$. Can we have the following:
$$lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty}lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty}A_{mn}=lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty }lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}A_{mn}=lim_{(m,n)\rightarrow \infty}A_{mn}?$$
Note that we assume this is in the extended real line with extra element $\infty$ and the limit should be always well defined due to monotonicity.

Answer (score 0):

$A_{mn}-A_{11}$ is non-negative,$m,n>=1$, so you can apply Fubini's theorem to interchange the order of that double sequence, then add $A_{11}$ back.

Comment: your construction is not correct since it violates that as $n$ fixed, $A_{mn}$ increases as $m$ increases.